# Android NFC read data from ePassport

Tags: android, nfc

I'm working on a ePassport Reader App, I've followed some older question and I've used the following code to connect to the passport successfully.
My problem is that I can't understand how can I read all data (name, surname, photo....) stored into the passport.
Here is the code I've used, the app is working well (prompt when is near an NFC tag).

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Tag... params) {

        //Tag tag = params[0];

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        //Log.d(TAG,"params " + intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG));

        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        IsoDep dep = IsoDep.get(tag);

        if (dep == null) {
            // IsoDep is not supported by this Tag. 
            return null;
        }

        byte[] CMD = {
                    (byte)0x00, /* CLA = 00 (first interindustry command set) */
                    (byte)0xA4, /* INS = A4 (SELECT) */
                    (byte)0x04, /* P1  = 04 (select file by DF name) */
                    (byte)0x0C, /* P2  = 0C (first or only file; no FCI) */
                    (byte)0x07, /* Lc  = 7  (data/AID has 7 bytes) */
                    /* AID = A0000002471001: */
                    (byte)0xA0, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x02,
                    (byte)0x47, (byte)0x10, (byte)0x01
            };

        byte[] GET_RANDOM = { 
                (byte) 0x00, // CLA Class        
                (byte) 0x84, // INS Instruction
                (byte) 0x00, // P1  Parameter 1
                (byte) 0x00, // P2  Parameter 2
                (byte) 0x0E  // LE  maximal number of bytes expected in result
            };

            try {
                dep.connect();

                byte[] result = dep.transceive(CMD);// CONNECT

                Log.d(TAG, "result " + result[0] + " " + (byte)0x90);

                if (!(result[0] == (byte) 0x90 && result[1] == (byte) 0x00))
                        throw new IOException("could not select applet");

                if(dep.isConnected()==true)
                    Log.d(TAG,"IS CONNECTED!");
                else
                    Log.d(TAG,"ISN'T CONNECTED!");

                    result = dep.transceive(GET_RANDOM); // EXEC A CMD
                    int len = result.length;
                    if (!(result[len-2]==(byte)0x90 && result[len-1]==(byte) 0x00))
                       throw new RuntimeException("could not retrieve msisdn");

                    byte[] data = new byte[len-2];
                    System.arraycopy(result, 0, data, 0, len-2);
                    String str = new String(data);

                    Log.d(TAG, str);

                    dep.close();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }



        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need the make a [BAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_control) (Basic Access Control) against your epassport to be able to read the basic informations printed on the passport (Country, Name, Surname, Nationality, Date of birth, Sex...) and the MRZ (Machine Readable Zone, that is to say the two big lines at the bottom of your passport). All this information is located in the DG (Data Group) 1, the photo is located in the DG2. You can find other informations in the other DG's except for example the DG3 which needs an EAC (Extended Access Control) to be read because it contains sensitive data (fingerprints).

You can use the [JMRTD](https://code.google.com/p/androsmex/source/browse/src/de/tsenger/) library to read it from your Android Phone. A "demo" Android application is available on the market [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.novay.nfcpassportreader&hl=fr). Otherwise, you can start reading the official documentation from ICAO (International Civil Aviation Organization) located [here](https://www.icao.int/publications/pages/publication.aspx?docnum=9303). At the end of this document, you can find some examples so you can make your own implementation of the BAC.

You can also look at [the JMRTD source code](https://code.google.com/p/androsmex/source/browse/src/de/tsenger/) to help you write your code. IMO it's quite complicated to code but very interesting to learn. The code you wrote is a good start!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I followed your advice and I've read the ICAO doc; I've added the following APDU to read DG1 data but the response I get is 6982.
`byte[] READ_BINARY = { 
                    (byte) 0x00, // CLA Class
                    (byte) 0xB0, // INS Instruction
                    (byte) 0x00, // P1  (indicate use of SFI)
                    (byte) 0x00, // P2  (SFI = 0x01)
                    (byte) 0x00  // LE  maximal number of bytes expected in result};`

Comment: 6982 means "Security condition not satisfied". You **have to** make a BAC before any SELECT or READ APDU. In few words, you need to ask a challenge from the passport, then make a SHA1 with the second line of the passport MRZ and many other things. A BAC implementation is available here https://code.google.com/p/androsmex/source/browse/src/de/tsenger/androsmex/bac/BACFunctions.java.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I've made a step forward and build the protected APDU, but somehow I get '6988' error (Incorrect secure messaging (SM) data object); I think that the error is on DO'87', I can't understand what the L parameter stands for (http://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p3_v2_cons_en.pdf at page 128).

Comment: There is many reasons for the 6988 error to appears. IMO a lot of coffee is needed to understand the process. There is a SM implementations available https://code.google.com/p/androsmex/source/browse/src/de/tsenger/androsmex/iso7816/SecureMessaging.java that can help you. You can also check the "WORKED EXAMPLES" p136-139 of the ICAO doc. Good luck!

Comment: @Louis Can you say more about how to use the EAC, needed to read the finger print data in DG3. Who's issuing this key and to whom is it distributed?

Comment: @user1147688 AFAIK, EAC not only authenticates the passport but also the reader (terminal). The keys "can be" distributed by diplomatic bags. There is a good infos on this german website https://www.bsi.bund.de/EN/Topics/ElectrIDDocuments/SecurityMechanisms/securPKI/securCVCA/securitymechanismsCVCA.html

Comment: Hi Dennis, Is it possible to create a tag with the same info as in the nfc chip for testing purposes ?.

Answer (score 7):

This is not an answer, but an addition to the info presented by Louis above.

---

**Here is the list of the various Data Group reference numbers:**

[image: LDS Data Group reference numbers]

---

**and here is an excerpt of the EAC description:**

[image: Security for additional biometrics]

Answer (score -8):

Usually the ePassport is protected against normal access. So, before reading the ePass one has to optically scan the data page, send it to a secure server (border control, etc.). They will check it, do a optical data recognition ([ocr](/questions/tagged/ocr)) and provide secure access to the integrated RFID chip. Therefore, it is not possible to create an app reading out an official passport. You may just read the UID in some passports or just detect that there is "something".

Comment: -1 The information required to generate the keys for BAC is printed in the machine-readable area at the bottom of the iformation page. THere is no need to send a scan of that page to some server backend. It is enough to type that information into an application. That app can then calculate the BAC keys **offline**. Btw. there is plenty of apps that **do** read information from electronic passports available on Play Store (e.g. [NFC TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo)).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was not aware that by possessing the optical information it is general possible to locally generate the keys to get electronic access to the passport.