# Reading EF.COM from ePassport fails at READ BINARY with rAPDU 6988 (Incorrect Secure Messaging Data Objects)

Tags: python, nfc, smartcard, apdu

First of all, I know this might look like a duplicate of: [ePassport reading with PN532, Keep Getting SW1 SW2 = 0x69 0x88 (Incorrect Secure Messaging Data Objects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486593/epassport-reading-with-pn532-keep-getting-sw1-sw2-0x69-0x88-incorrect-secure)

..but I'm one step further in the process.

I'm trying to read a MRTD (ePassport) using python and a PN7120 nfc reader. I used [pyPassport 2.0](https://github.com/andrew867/epassportviewer/tree/master/pypassport-2.0) as a basis.

I know the reader is OK because I can read passports with the same device using a Android setup.

I followed [the ICAO 9303 Part 11 documentation](https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p11_cons_en.pdf), and simulated the "worked example" (appendix D, same file).

**The problem**

When using a real passport, the steps "select applet", "get challenge", "do bac", and "select file" step work fine but read binary results in 69 88 (Incorrect Secure Messaging Data Objects).

When I simulate the "worked example" by injecting the ksmac/ssc I get to the exact same ProtectedAPDU outcome as stated on page 75 (AppD-7) point g.

Also, the step "select file" almost uses the exact same procedure (see [def protect](https://github.com/andrew867/epassportviewer/blob/master/pypassport-2.0/pypassport/doc9303/securemessaging.py)) with success (rAPDU 90 00).

I've compared everything in to extreme detail at least twice and really don't see where to look next. I hope someone can give some advice or insights.

**The relevant log (error at the end)**

```
Calculate Session Keys (KSenc and KSmac) using Appendix 5.1
        KSenc: 3DE649F8AEA41C04FB6D4CD9043757AD
        KSmac: 8C34AD61974F68CEBA3E0EAEA1456476
Calculate Send Sequence Counter
        SSC: AB1D2F337FD997D6

Reading Common
Select File
    APDU 00 A4 02 0C 02 [011E]
Mask class byte and pad command header
        CmdHeader: 0CA4020C80000000
Pad data
        Data: 011E800000000000
Encrypt data with KSenc 3DE649F8AEA41C04FB6D4CD9043757AD
        EncryptedData: FF0E241E2F94B508
Build DO'87
        DO87: 870901FF0E241E2F94B508
Concatenate CmdHeader and DO87
        M: 0CA4020C80000000870901FF0E241E2F94B508
Compute MAC of M
        Increment SSC with 1
                SSC: AB1D2F337FD997D7
        Concatenate SSC and M and add padding
                N: AB1D2F337FD997D70CA4020C80000000870901FF0E241E2F94B5088000000000
        Compute MAC over N with KSmac 8C34AD61974F68CEBA3E0EAEA1456476
                CC: 22FF803EC3104336
Build DO'8E
        DO8E: 8E0822FF803EC3104336
Construct and send protected APDU
        ProtectedAPDU: 0CA4020C15870901FF0E241E2F94B5088E0822FF803EC310433600
[SM] - 0C A4 02 0C 15 [870901FF0E241E2F94B5088E0822FF803EC3104336] 00
[SM] - [990290008E08AAEA3B783FD6CA9D] 90 00
Receive response APDU of MRTD's chip
        RAPDU: 990290008E08AAEA3B783FD6CA9DC29000

Read Binary
    APDU 00 B0 00 00  [] 04
Mask class byte and pad command header
        CmdHeader: 0CB0000080000000
Build DO'97
        DO97: 970104
Concatenate CmdHeader and DO97
        M: 0CB0000080000000970104
Compute MAC of M
        Increment SSC with 1
                SSC: AB1D2F337FD997D8
        Concatenate SSC and M and add padding
                N: AB1D2F337FD997D80CB00000800000009701048000000000
        Compute MAC over N with KSmac 8C34AD61974F68CEBA3E0EAEA1456476
                CC: 68DD9FD88472834A
Build DO'8E
        DO8E: 8E0868DD9FD88472834A
Construct and send protected APDU
        ProtectedAPDU: 0CB000000D9701048E0868DD9FD88472834A00
[SM] - 0C B0 00 00 0D [9701048E0868DD9FD88472834A] 00
[SM] - [] 69 88 //SM data objects incorrect
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I get the exact same results for the two protected APDUs. But aren't you supposed to start SSC at zero (if this is secure messaging after BAC)?

Comment: Never mind about SSC zero. BAC starts SSC at a value based on the exchanged randoms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

Due to a binary/hex/string conversion error ([here](https://github.com/andrew867/epassportviewer/blob/master/pypassport-2.0/pypassport/doc9303/securemessaging.py#L127)) the SM validation step for the SELECT FILE response was skipped and thus the SSC wasn't incremented correctly.